# Objective-C Unit Tests cannot find my resources

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode

When i run unit tests it fails on loading external resources (images) with the same error as if they don't exist.  In xcode i have added the resources to the unit test target.  I don't know what to try next.

I am using the Cocos2d framework, I try to load the following code within a unit test

`AtlasSpriteManager *at = [AtlasSpriteManager spriteManagerWithFile:@"player2.png" capacity:50];`

It seems this actually calls 

`UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile`

which returns nil.

The actual code that throws the error looks like

`image = [uiImage CGImage];
if(image == NULL) {
 [self release];
 NSLog(@"Image is Null");
 return nil;
}`

It seems that the images required are not copied over to the Application Support directory before the unit tests run, only after a successful pass.  I am not sure if this is the problem, but if it is is there a way to change the build order so the images are copied first and the unit tests can find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources most likely aren't getting included into the target.  So before you have your Run Script phase of your test bundle, make sure you have a "Copy Resources" phase that copies the resources into the test bundle that the tests will need.

Comment: I regularly fail to include the proper targets for my resources. More than actual code failure, is this that raises alarms.

Comment: I do have a copy bundle resource phase.  I am following the apple documentation on unit tests, so i have my duplicated project that adds the copy bundle resource PROJNAME.octest, this expanded has the image resources.  Then in the unit test bundle target there is also a copy bundle resource phase that contains my images.  I am assuming it is before the run script phase as it is higher in the tree when i expand the target.